# Understanding the graph of tf.cond

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to understand the inner workings of tf.cond by looking at the graph of low-level ops that are used to build it.

This is the code in question

```
x = tf.constant(1, name='x')
y = tf.constant(2, name='y')
z = tf.constant(3, name='z')

result = tf.cond(tf.less(x, y), lambda: tf.add(x, z), lambda: tf.square(y))
```

And the resulting [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIJSx.jpg).

What I am wondering is the following.

- What is the separate switch op leading to switch_t and switch_f doing there?
- Why does Less output connect to pred_id and Switch Ops? I would expect it to output one predicate (Boolean tensor) leading into all Switch-es for all the inputs into tf.cond.
- What is pred_id? Is it just an identity that forks the predicate into three branches?
- I am trying to understand how does tf.cond evaluate only one branch during runtime.

  I understand that when we evaluate the result of tf.cond we are evaluating the tensor coming out of the merge op. Merge must take in (I assume) four tensors as input (two from Add branch and two from Square branch) and three of which much be dead. But we only can know the "deadness" of the tensors if we eval them back down the graph, no?
- For the Square branch, for example, I understand that switch takes in as input the y tensor and the predicate and outputs two tensors, y and dead, on the appropriate branches of the switch statement. But this branch is kind of guaranteed already to be for the false branch. So what happens to both T and F outputs of the switch branch? They both go into Square Op? And then into the merge?

Thank you,

S

Comment: Which version of TF are you using?

Comment: tensorflow 1.13.1